# Calling multiple API in sequence using RxJava,Retrofit,RxKotlin flatmap

Tags: android, kotlin, flatmap

I need to call 3 different api ...each api takes input of another api output in sequence..

eg : API1 -> output -> will be input for API2
     API2 -> output -> will be input for API3

In my case , Spinner contain API1 ....On spinner selection i need to call API2 and so on
Currently i am writing a separate code for each API and call them using Observer...but i want to call APIs in sequence using RxJava,RxKotlin and Retrofit flatmap concepts.So is there any way using that, i can call this three APIs in sequence, without writing each of them seperatly

Comment: [you can follow below link for chaining of API calling using flatMap](https://blog.doordash.com/synchronizing-network-calls-with-rxjava-d30f7db66fb9) if using Kotlin then follow [Chaining Multiple Retrofit Call Using RxJava/ Kotlin](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e)